# Custom Twitter SignIn experience

Tags: ios, twitter

I would like to be able to customise the twitter sign in ViewController, because I want to customise the UINavigationBar at the top, and set a Custom ViewController Transition. **I've customised the YouTube signInVC like so:**
[image]
..and I would now like to do the same with twitter's sign in experience.

**I'm currently using this code:**

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        // play with Twitter session
    }];
    logInButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

**.. that springs this, not so customisable, result:**
[image]

- Dan

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to be using oAuth for anybody out there wondering.